# How to implement a Physical Data Model without Foreign Keys in PowerDesigner

Tags: oracle, database-design, constraints, powerdesigner

I have a PDM in Power Designer that I need to implement on my Oracle database.

I want to test two cases, one with the constraints like Primary Key & Foreign Key and one without those constraints.

I don't know how to do the 2nd case, do I need to use Unique Indexes ? How can it work like a fk in my diagram ? How can avoid to implement the foreign keys but still have them in my diagram ? Is there an option to not enforce the foreign key in my database ?

I can't find any or proper way to deal with the 2nd case

Thanks for your help

Comment: I see two options: on the Reference itself, on the main page of the property sheet, you have a Generate checkbox. On in `Database > Generate Database`, `Options` tab, in `All Objects > Table & Column > Foreign key`, you have a `Create foreign key` checkbox.

Comment: Oh right, thanks for your help !
Have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pascal's comment do the trick :

> On in Database > Generate Database, Options tab, in All Objects >
>   Table & Column > Foreign key, you have a Create foreign key checkbox